# How to call .NET Web Api from Android App ?

Tags: android, json, web-services, authentication

I have an android login app which post two parameters i.e username and password. These 2 parameters are passed as json. The problem is I m not able to call the .net web api. This api confirms the login details and response I get from the page is id = 0 message "null"
I dont know where i am going wrong.

The complete source code

```
package com.hmkcode.android;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.hmkcode.android.vo.Person;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView tvIsConnected;
EditText etName,etCountry,etTwitter;
Button btnPost;

Person person;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get reference to the views
    tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCountry);

    btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);

    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are connected");
    }
    else{
        tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT connected");
    }

    // add click listener to Button "POST"
    btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public static String POST(String url, Person person){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject login = new JSONObject();

       login.accumulate("Email", person.getName());
        login.accumulate("Password", person.getCountry());




        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String

        json = login.toString();

        JSONObject finaldata = new JSONObject();
        finaldata.put("LoginRequestTemp", json);

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
       inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();



        // 10. convert inputstream to string


        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

        else
            result = "Did not work!";

   } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
   }




     //         11. return result
             return result;
                }


    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
       (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
                return true;
            else
                return false;    
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnPost:
                if(!validate())
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Enter some data!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
                new HttpAsyncTask().execute
              ("http://dev.blinkawards.com/blinkawards.RestService/Service1/LoginTemp");
            break;
        }

    }
    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            person = new Person();
            person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
            person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());


            return POST(urls[0],person);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }

    private boolean validate(){
        if(etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if(etCountry.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;

        else
            return true;    
    }


    private static String convertInputStreamToString
      (InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader
       ( new   InputStreamReader(inputStream));
       String line = "";
       String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

       inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting the password to the country? Is it supposed to be like that? login.accumulate("Password", person.getCountry());